# Java Swing multithread management with observer pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, observer-pattern, swingworker

My goal is to draw a rectangle and move it smoothly from left to right, using Observer pattern.

I have a Model class, which is the Observable where I put the coordinates of the rectangle, and a Display class which is the Observer and perform repaint each time the coordinates change in the Model.

The coordinates changes in the Model are made in a while loop inside a SwingWorker : at each iteration I increment the x coordinate by one, then sleep for 100 ms, then notify the Observer (the Display) which only task is to perform a repaint. As you see the repaint() method is called on the EDT like it is adviced to do.

The problem is that the move isn't smooth after about one second, the repaint frequency change and it seems that the rectangle is less and less repainted.

Here is the Model class :

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Model extends Observable{
    int xCoordinate;

    Model(Display d){
        SwingWorker<Void,Void> sw = new SwingWorker<Void,Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() {
                while(xCoordinate<600){
                    xCoordinate ++;

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers(xCoordinate);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        addObserver(d);
        sw.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] a){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Display d = new Display();
                Model m = new Model(d);
                d.model = m;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the Display class :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Display extends JFrame implements Observer{
    Model model;
    int xCoordinate;

    Display(){
        getContentPane().add(new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(xCoordinate, 1, 50, 50);
            }
        });
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    /* arg is the updated xCoordinate*/
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        xCoordinate = (Integer)arg;
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                repaint();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

I tried other methods, for instance using Timer in the Display, but that didn't work either. The SwingWorker maybe isn't useful here because calculations made on the SwingWorker thread are easy (increment by one) but I will need it for the heavy calculations I intend to do on my project (a pool game).

I also tried debugging by looking at time between two repaints (in Display) and time between two incrementations (in Model) and it was as expected about 100 ms each.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you change the sleep time? Try with 10 ms, it will move more smoothly.

Comment: Well it is still not smooth (on my computer at least). I tried 10 and 500 ms.

Comment: I tried an example using `javax.swing.Timer`, but setting the delay to 100 ms it doesn't move smoothly. Here's the example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Timerbasedanimation.htm.

Comment: Beware of the fact that `Thread.sleep(long milis)` is subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. It may not always sleep exactly the given time to sleep, may take longer.

Comment: I'd be conserved with synchronisation issues between the worker/observer and the paint routine

Comment: @A2H I tried your example but it doesn't move smoothly on my computer whatever delay value I pass as argument of the timer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer But since I call repaint() in a EventQueue.invokeLater() I let Swing do what it should do so what could be the problem ?

Comment: @Alsvartr `repaint` is actually one of the few thread safe methods in Swing, but you're modifying `xCoordinate` in a different thread from which `paintComponent` is been called, which could lead to dirty reads

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so as an initial test, I started with a Swing `Timer`...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Model model = new Model();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane(model));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                                                model.update();
                                                            }
                                                        });
                timer.setInitialDelay(1000);
                timer.start();
            }

        });
    }

    public class Model extends Observable {

        private int xCoordinate;

        public void update() {
            xCoordinate++;
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(xCoordinate);
        }

        public int getXCoordinate() {
            return xCoordinate;
        }

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Observer {

        private Model model;

        public TestPane(Model model) {
            this.model = model;
            model.addObserver(this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(model.getXCoordinate(), 1, 50, 50);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            System.out.println(arg);
            repaint();
        }

    }

}
```

The thing I found was, you never call `setChanged` on the `Observable`, which during my testing, meant that it never called the `Observer`s

I also did a test with a `SwingWorker`...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Model model = new Model();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane(model));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        while (true) {
                            model.update();
                        }
                    }
                };
                worker.execute();
            }

        });
    }

    public class Model extends Observable {

        private int xCoordinate;

        public synchronized void update() {
            xCoordinate++;
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(xCoordinate);
        }

        public synchronized int getXCoordinate() {
            return xCoordinate;
        }

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Observer {

        private Model model;

        public TestPane(Model model) {
            this.model = model;
            model.addObserver(this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(model.getXCoordinate(), 1, 50, 50);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            System.out.println(arg);
            repaint();
        }

    }

}
```

Because of the thread synchronization issues, I synchronized access to the methods to ensure that values weren't changing between updates.  Because you're using an `Observer`, could actually pass the "new state" to the `Observer`, so they aren't reliant on then value of the model at the time they use them.

Okay, so the long and short of it, you need to call `setChanged` on the `Observable` once it's been updated, so that `notifyObservers` will actually call the `Observer`s

As someone undoubtedly point out, this approach suffers from inaccuracies in the timing, by it's nature, both Swing `Timer` and `Thread.sleep` only guarantee a "at least" timing and may verify between each update.

If you have a variable length operation, this will also affect the time between updates.  Instead, you should be calculating the time it took you to perform your operation, subtract the amount of time you want to wait, you would then use this delay to calculate how long you want to "wait" between frames.  You should also be using `System.nanoTime` over `System.currentTimeMillis` as it won't suffer from the same system clock synchronization issues

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I think I see what you mean, but the animation is still not smooth on my computer when I put Thread.sleep(100) in the while(true) loop of the SwingWorker (on your second example). So the problem comes from the inaccuracies of Thread.sleep() ? And how can I deal with it ? because even with your answer to calculate how long I want to "wait" I'll have to use Thread.sleep right ?

Comment: No, I'd say it comes down to the fact that's only running at 10fps (1000/100) (and the synchronisation, which is slow), I'd consider decreasing the delay (40 is 25fps, 16 is 60fps) and see what difference it makes.  Depending on what you're trying to do, a time based approach might be more appropriate.  That is, given a certain amount of time, move the object a certain distance, if done correctly the algorithm can "drop" frames which can give a better illusion of movement